# Поменять текст ошибки для случая, когда слишком длинное значение ввёл в поле местоположения

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то не по-русски звучит.

Предлагаю заменить на:

> Поле ввода местоположения ограничено X символами; вы ввели Y

Comment: Но ведь если удалось ввести больше, значит «поле ввода» не имеет такого ограничения.

Comment: @alexolut хм. Интересно. Надо тогда ещё подумать)

Comment: @alexolut может "в названии местоположения"?